# AMPscript in Subject Line breaks in A/B Test email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

We sent out an [A/B test email](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/ab_testing/) with the following subject line:

```
%%[IF NOT EMPTY(NM_FIRSTNAME) AND LENGTH(NM_FIRSTNAME) > 1 THEN ]%%
%%NM_FIRSTNAME%%, s
%%[ ELSE ]%%S
%%[ ENDIF ]%%ee your super in Product Name
```

The email sent without issue, however when the 'winning' email was sent, then the email failed to send.

After investigation it appears to be an AMPscript related issue, as we can see that the subject line changed to:

```
%%[IF NOT EMPTY(NM_FIRSTNAME) AND LENGTH(NM_FIRSTNAME) &gt; 1 THEN ]%%
%%NM_FIRSTNAME%%, s
%%[ ELSE ]%%S
%%[ ENDIF ]%%ee your super in Product Name
```

Note the `&gt;` character replacement. Has anyone seen this before and if so, do you know of a workaround?

Refer to screenshots below from Send Tracking pages.

### A/B Test Send

[image: a/b test]

### Winning Email

> Note no emails were sent.

[image: winning email]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why that happened in the winning email. Looks like a bug.

I suppose you could try moving the subject line conditional to a script block in the email.

Something like this:

**Init block in the email**

```
%%[ /* Modify to view AMPScript <div style="display:none;"> */

var @fn, @subject
set @fn = AttributeValue("NM_FIRSTNAME")

IF NOT EMPTY(@fn) and LENGTH(@fn) > 1 THEN
 set @subject = concat(@fn,", s")
ELSE 
  set @subject = "S"
ENDIF

set @subject = concat(@subject, "ee your super in Product Name")

/* </div> */
]%%
```

**Subject**

```
%%=v(@subject)=%%
```

Comment: So this works which is great, but can you think of any reason why my original approach of including this in the subject line would not work? Would you consider this to be a defect of the A/B testing feature?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your original scripting.  I've seen that done before, but since the A/B testing has a subject line testing option, I'm guessing that it's getting unnecessarily encoded at some point in that process.